# upload csv file to databricks workspace programatically

Tags: databricks

I get an excel file every day via email. if I want to use it in databricks I can upload the file to DBFS and create a dataframe out of it. However, instead of uploading the file to DBFS everyday I would like to either automate the upload or somehow read the excel file (located in sharepoint) from Databricks. Is this possible?